# Laravel - How to pass variable to reset password template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have implemented reset password functionality with `Laravel 5` and getting email. Now how to pass some variable data to my email template to display more information about user.

```
/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    //echo Input::get('ID'); die;
    $this->validate($request, ['ID' => 'required|email']);

    $UserProduct = "Sample 1"; // I want to pass this variable to my password.blade.php
    $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('ID'), function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['ID' => trans($response)]);
    }

}
```

I want to print `$UserProduct = "Sample 1";` to my email template but don't  know how to pass to the `password.blade` page.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, don't know right now, `with` accepts an array? `'with->(array('status'=>...,'product'=>...);` Check out the method implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sendResetLink` doesn't have a proper way to send more data like a regular email in laravel.

You can kinda hack around this using [a view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers), something like this:

```
$UserProduct = "Sample 1";
$infoArray = [1,2,3,4];

view()->composer('emails.auth.password', function($view) use ($UserProduct, $infoArray) {
    $view->with([
        'UserProduct' => $UserProduct,
        'info' => $infoArray,
        'more' => 'Even more info',
    ]);
});

$response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('ID'), function (Message $message) {
    $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support but In future I have to pass more variable to my email template how to do that?

Comment: @Mr.Happy Hi, I updated the answer with a way to add more variables.

Comment: Thanks now I am getting data to my reset password email template :)