# How to attach variable to reset password link view in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 where I need to sent an OTP code to reset password, though email is being sent with built in subject and limited message done by make:auth command but how to customize? I have tried to follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529750/laravel-how-to-pass-variable-to-reset-password-template) unfortunately I am unable to understand how i can use this to solve.

I customized the api like this

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $email = $request->input('email');

    $userid = DB::table('users')->where('email','=',$email)->value('id');

    $uniqueotp = "DIYA".uniqid();
    $curr_timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    $date = strtotime("+7 day", $curr_timestamp);
    $expiry_otp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
    $ip_address = $request->ip();

    DB::table('otp_users')->insert([
            'user_id' => $userid, 
            'status' => 0, 
            'otp_code' => $uniqueotp,
            'ipaddress'=>$ip_address,
            'expires_at'=>$expiry_otp
          ]);  

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
        $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($request,$response);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve?

My required email message like this:

```
Hello, Tamaghna Banerjee Click here to reset your password: 
Your OTP is: B16445512121
Reset Your Password through http://localhost/diya/public/password/reset/83baba9f61fc851b9d80b515415ec86c43b03b56b068e1888256db7a7831ba83?email=tamaghnabanerjee%40live.com
```

Comment: See above I have updated it..

Comment: job is done by  view()->share('otp', $uniqueotp);