# laravel 5.4 Using a custom database template to send resetpassword email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, reset-password

I am new to laravel, I am working on project in which I've been asked to use a custom database template to send reset password email how can I update the existing email template to use a template in database to send the email.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you mean by 'database template'?

Comment: yes i am using crudbooster in laravel in it we can define the template to send mail the template which i want to use is stored in database it's like this

<p>Hi,</p><p>Someone requested forgot password, here is your the link to reset your password: </p><p>[link]</p><p><br></p><p>--</p><p>Regards,</p><p>Admin</p>

i want to use this instead of already available template
i want to use template from database so that the backend user can define the template in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

The password reset email is found in the view:

`resources\views\auth\passwords\reset.blade.php`

Replace the HTML in that view with a raw database call to get your template content.

Also, you might want to check out [Laravel - How to pass variable to reset password template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529750/laravel-how-to-pass-variable-to-reset-password-template) about passing additional data to the reset password email.